# JavaScript и БД

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных

Преподаватель задал курсовую. Задача состоит в поиске информации в БД. Но условием является выполнение на чистом JS, без PHP и других языков. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, это вообще реально? И если да, то как или что почитать?

Comment: есть такая вещь, попробуйте связать SQlite  c JS. Должно получится. Только, когда вопрос задаете, постарайтет вкладыват свои попитки решения. 2) если знаете анг. может это поможет http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

Comment: Почему бы у препода не уточнить что за БД такая. БД понятие растяжимое, может и есть какая-нибудь, в которой прямо js-ом ищут

Comment: преподаватель неадекватный, ни на какие вопросы не отвечает

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov может препод имел в виду Local Storage DB?там можно и релативную БД накатать в браусвере, и на чистом JS работает?

Comment: Ох уж эти преподаватели)

Comment: Только что искать в этих Local Storage. Потребуй смену препода за неадыкватность.

Comment: думаю над жалобой на препода, но вот люди ниже вариант на html5 предложили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HTML5* позволяет без лишних библиотек, напрямую работать с базами данных (на стороне клиента).

Вот пример: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/84654/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/wa-html5db/index.html

Если БД на стороне клиента, а не на сервере является допустимым - можете использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо уточнение какую БД надо использовать.

**Свою**

*1 Вариант - неизменяемая база*

Создаем `JSON` с данными, загружаем ее через `AJAX` в своем скрипте и пишем функцию `find`. Пример:

```js
var db = [{
  'name': 'Alex',
  'gender': 'male'
}, {
  'name': 'Lisa',
  'gender': 'feemale'
}, {
  'name': 'Alfred',
  'gender': 'male'
}];

function find(dbObj, query) {
  return dbObj.filter(function(el) {
    for (var name in query) {
      if (query.hasOwnProperty(name) &&
        el[name] !== query[name]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
}

var result = find(db, {
  gender: 'male'
});

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

```css
body {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

*2 вариант - Изменяемую базу:*

Создаем простую базу с методами: `create`, `update`, `delete`, `find` прямо в `JavaScript`. Сохранять данные можно в `WebStorage`. Т.е. работа просто с массивом, функцию `find` можно взять из предыдущего примера.

**Чужую реализацию БД**

В интернете есть несколько реализаций таких баз данных. Можно найти по тексту "Javascript Offline Database"

**NodeJS**

Не надо забывать, что есть серверная реализация JavaScript. Самые популярные на данный момент базы на `Node` это MySql и [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/).

Если с базами работали мало, рекомендую именно `MongoDB` - проще понять.

Книга по монге - http://jsman.ru/mongo-book/

**Update**

Еще можно использовать html-страницу как базу данных, а далее использовать методы поиска по селекторам.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая разработка называется [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)

Разработчик член нашего SO [@agershun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/26767/agershun)

Смысл в том, что вся СУБД написана на чистом JavaScript - вполне подходит под вашу задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Если допускается использование node.js,то проблем не возникает вобще,там возможен прямой доступ к БД.

PS. Есть еше извращенный вариант,без ноды. Берете Cordova ,собираете приложение под нужную платформу. Там тоже есть API для работы с БД.